# How to get the roothash or a proof from a child trie in substrate?

Tags: rust, storage, substrate, merkle-tree

According to the example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/d5f18844cef2f2a0c218c7778a81b4328c16f40e/runtime/src/crowdfund.rs#L447), I see one could use the `srml_support::storage::child` API to create a merkle sub trie out of arbitrary data. But how can we get the merkle root or a proof for a particular leaf using this? I see the [API](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v1.0/srml_support/storage/child/index.html) doesn't provide any functions named as such.

Comment: You tagged your question with `substrate`, would you be interested in a dedicated Stack Exchange Q&A site for Substrate, Polkadot, et al. -- check out the [Area51 Substrate Proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122626/substrate?referrer=NTUwMTkxYjJjOTJiNjE0YzMxYjgwMGNkZmFlYzdhZTczYjk1ZWY3ZGI4NzJmODUwN2RlYTQ2MTNjZTdkOTZhMAzuL-zybtPN9CHzwE-WUdvBC8WxvPG46b4ayadke6kG0)

Comment: Hey VIM, we are trying again to open a dedicated Substrate StackExchange. Can you take a look and support the proposal? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 4):

The `srml_support::storage::child` API make use of [`sr_io`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v1.0/sr_io/) API.

`sr_io` provides more functionality, for example [sr_io::child_storage_root](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v1.0/sr_io/fn.child_storage_root.html) which is the function you are looking for.

Comment: how do I obtain a proof for a leaf of a child trie? I see the above API do not have such a function.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to directly query the parent trie node containing the root. For the linked exemple it will be something like this (child_storage_root is doing calculation of ongoing change whereas querying directly the root get the state at the start of the block processing or the latest stored state calculation):

```
let id = Self::id_from_index(index);
let child_root = storage::unhashed::get_raw(id.as_ref());
```